# Item not updated

Tags: item, update

I'm trying update list item created by workflow, using code below. But it did not work. What I am doing wrong?

```
public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdated(properties);

        SPList Listcurrent = properties.Web.Lists["Tasks"];
        SPListItem taskid = Listcurrent.GetItemById(properties.ListItemId);

        taskid["%5Fx041d%5F%5Fx0430%5F%5Fx0437%5F%5Fx0432%5F%5Fx04"] = "Hello World!";               

         taskid.Update();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: taskid["columnname"], is "%5Fx041d%5F%5Fx0430%5F%5Fx0437%5F%5Fx0432%5F%5Fx04" this your  column name ?

Comment: you can debug your event receiver and then share the error.

Comment: Do you want to update the same item?

Comment: Hardik, yes the same as in properties

Comment: Akarsh Gupta, yes its the name displaying in browser after "&Field="

Comment: You could just add a step in the workflow itself?

Comment: The problem is in this string  taskid["%5Fx041d%5F%5Fx0430%5F%5Fx0437%5F%5Fx0432%5F%5Fx04"] = "Hello World!";   If i comment it -everythig ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of update problem.

The code does not work whith field name "`%5Fx041d%5F%5Fx0430%5F%5Fx0437%5F%5Fx0432%5F%5Fx04`".

But"strange" name of the field is correct. The reason- russian letters in the field name.

To solve this problem decode field name to internal name. How to get it?

Go to [this blog](http://ehikioya.com/get-sharepoint-internal-names-with-url-decoding/)

And then decode field name in "`URL Encoder And Decoder Tool`"  unit.

For me internal name is "`_x041d__x0430__x0437__x0432__x04`".

And new code will be, and it works:

```
taskid["_x041d__x0430__x0437__x0432__x04"] = "Hello World!";               

taskid.Update();
```